# How to view mono MLPD files for profiling

Tags: memory-leaks, mono, monodevelop

I built MonoDevelop using [these instructions](https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/#windows). I compiled a console application with it and it's running on a Linux machine. I have noticed a memory leak and would like to track it and figure out what is being leaked.

According to [these instructions](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/profile/profiler/#basic-profiler-usage), I must start the application with specific options in mono. At that point, the profilier will dump an MLPD file. I now have that file and would like to view it and see what's going on. I can not find this `mprof-report` program anywhere.

Has it been depricated? If so, how do we profile mono applications now? There isn't much about it online.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has it been depricated?

No, it is a part of the Mono distribution and is a C-based program so it is a "native" binary and located in the "bin" directory along with `mono`, `mono64` `pedump`, `monograph`, `monodis`, etc..

On MacOS these are located in:

```
file `which mprof-report`
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mprof-report: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Man page:

```
NAME
       mprof-report - report generator for Mono's log profiler

SYNOPSIS
       mprof-report [option]... file.mlpd

DESCRIPTION
       mprof-report  is  the report generator for Mono's log profiler. It reads the MLPD log
       files produced by the log profiler and generates a report based on the options passed
       to  it.  The output is based on individual reports which can be turned on or off.  By
       default, all reports are generated in summary form (i.e., non-verbose output).

       mprof-report can read both normal and gzip(1)-compressed log files transparently.

       For information about how to use the log profiler with a program, see  the  mono-pro-
       filers(1) page, under the LOG PROFILER section.
        ~~~~~
```

Comment: I am on Windows 10. I installed the mono runtimes and did a system wide search for the profiler and it doesn't exist. Where is it on Windows? Did i use the wrong installer?

Comment: OK -- that was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Andy , I'm having the exact same problem as you... Can you be a little more clear regarding how you ran `mprof-report` in windows?

Comment: @ViníciusQueiroz Sorry to be the bringer of bad news.. but I was having the issue on Linux and it's automatically installed with the `mono-complete` package and located here: `/usr/bin/mprof-report` I don't remember if I ever used it on windows.